# Doubts in a code to test the use of assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I am writing a code to test the use of assignment operator and copy constructor. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class fun {
  int i;
  public:
         fun():i(1) {i=1;cout<<"in: cons\n";}
         ~fun() {cout<<"in: des\n";}
         fun& operator=(fun b) {
              cout<<"in: assignOp\n";
              swap(this->i, b.i);
              return *this;
         }
         fun(fun& b) {
              cout<<"in: copy cons\n";
              b.i = this->i;
         }
         void print() {
              cout<<i<<endl;
         }
};

main() 
{
   fun A;
   fun B;
   B = A;
   A.print();
}
```

And here is the output of the code:

> in: cons
>
> in: cons
>
> in: copy cons
>
> in: assignOp
>
> in: des
>
> -1216991244
>
> in: des
>
> in: des

Now, there are 2 things that I can't understand about the output.

Firstly, why is the code going in the copy constructor function?
Secondly, why is the value of 'i' is being printed as garbage instead of '1'?

I am a newbie so excuse me if my doubt is obvious.

Comment: Your assignment operator, besides the problems described in the answers, isn't actually an _assignment_. If you want to do a swap, then you should make a `swap` function instead. Changing the semantics of an operator will not only confuse others, it will probably confuse yourself a couple of months down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B = A;
```

This is causing the assignment operator to be called. The reason you see `copy cons` in the output is because your assignment operator takes its argument by value. So `A` is copied into the assignment operator function, which requires the copy constructor to be used.

Both copy constructors and copy assignment operators usually take their arguments by `const` reference.

The reason you get the garbage value is because you have this line backwards:

```
b.i = this->i;
```

It should be:

```
this->i = b.i;
```

Otherwise, your copy constructor copies the indeterminate value of `this->i` into the object you are copying from.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, why is the code going in the copy constructor function?

The copy constructor is invoked when the argument is copied for the assignment operator. You're passing the argument to the assignment operator by value, instead of a reference:

```
fun& operator=(fun b)
```

instead of

```
fun& operator=(const fun& b)
```

> Secondly, why is the value of 'i' is being printed as garbage instead of '1'?

In your copy constructor, you're assigning the wrong way around:

```
b.i = this->i;
```

instead of

```
this->i = b.i;
```